# using FileChooser to save a file with default filename

Tags: javafx-2

I wat to save a file.I use this.

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
```

But in the dialog I want to suggest a name for the file, so that the user only selects a directory for the given file.The name of the file is known already.So i want to suggest that filename.

ThankYou.

Comment: Since this isn't directly doable with JavaFX 2.2 (as answered below) you could ask to select a directory where such file exists.  Then when selected make sure the file with given name is there.

Answer (score 10):

This is now fixed in Javafx 2.2.45 (bundled with java 7.0_45 now) and you can do what the OP is suggesing with the following property of fileChooser, setInitialFilename, used as such:

```
        FileChooser myFile = new FileChooser();
        myFile.setInitialFileName("Whatever_file_I_want.coolFile");
```

Now, I don't think there is anyway to STOP the user from choosing a different file, but at leas this will give them a default you want them to pick.

Answer (score 4):

Initial file name providing - it is a thing, which requires to transfer your string (initial name)  through native call, to the call of the native file chooser. It is a complex thing, and you can look at these issues about its implementing :

http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-16111 (main one)

http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24588

http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24612

They all have fix version lombard, so, they are fixed in JDK 8.

So, you can specify initial file name for a file, starting from JDK 8 (you can access it, downloading JDK early access).

Recently, I've tested this feature, and it is working.

There is a method setInitialName() or smth like that.

And, as I've mentioned, it is a complex thing, and you are not likely to be able to implement it by yourself (until you are able to build jfx).

So, the decision - to wait until JDK8 release, or to use early access builds. Or, to use your own implementation of file chooser.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround that worked for me:

you can use javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser to select a directory for the file you want to save and after saving create a new file in this directory with the default name and extension.

```
DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();
File file = dc.showDialog(null);
if (file != null) {
            file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/dafaultFilename.extension");}
```